# Flutter android studio import package path

Tags: flutter, dart

this is new project，`import` package has no problem.

[image]

My other project is like this:

[image]

what happend？help me.

Comment: Why not just create a new project? Maybe something went wrong when you were creating that project?

Comment: delete `.dart_tool` folder and restart IDE

Comment: hey Eugene，thanks，I delete .dart_tool ,is right.Thank you for solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

as Eugene said delete .dart_tool and restart IDE